# scrape a website using ajax to load date using php

Tags: ajax, web-scraping

my question is how I can scrape a website that loads it's date with ajax technology. for example, if you click on the link of page `2`, it loads the data with ajax. here is the link [this url](https://www.ottawatourism.ca/events/).
when I inspect the `XHR` I find the params:

```
<?php
$param=array('page'=>2,'security'=>'a5db027292','action'=>'evetn);
$url='https://www.ottawatourism.ca/events/?page='.$param['page'].'&action=events_see_more&security='.$param['security'];
$sitecontent=file_get_content($url);
$dom= new DOMDocumnet();
$dom->loadHTML($sitecontent);
$xpath= new DOMXpath($dom);
$nodes= $xpath->query('//div[@class="link-tile"]/a/@href');
foreach($nodes as $link){
     var_dump($link->nodeValue);
}
?>
```

it seems something wrong with my code because if I put `page=5` , I get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of tutorials out there to accomplish such things.
I don't think stackoverflow is here to provide you fully functional code and build completely your website :)

Comment: @ I was digging in the Internet but unfortunately no results. could you put links here to redirect .